# IE 7 Ajax call breaking

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

The ajax call in fiddler is happening and returning a 200 OK with a json response however the onload function is erroring out and the error shown is "Object doesn't support this property or method" on line xdr.onload

```
    if($.browser.msie) {

      if(window.XDomainRequest == undefined) {
        var xdr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
      } else {
        var xdr = new XDomainRequest();  
      }

      xdr.open("post", ajaxStatusUrl+"?buster="+ new Date().getTime());

      setTimeout(function() {
        xdr.send();
      }, 1000);

      xdr.onload = function() {
        var JSON = $.parseJSON(xdr.responseText);

        if(JSON == null || typeof (JSON) == 'undefined') {
          JSON = $.parseJSON(data.firstChild,textContent);
        }
        processData(JSON);
      };

      xdr.onprogress = function() {};
      xdr.ontimeout = function() {};
      xdr.onerror = function() {
        alert('error');
      };

    } else {

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: ajaxStatusUrl+"?buster="+ new Date().getTime(),
          processData: true,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            processData(data);
          }
        });
      }
  });
```

Comment: Where's the IE10 test? IE10 can use $.ajax just like any of the other modern browsers. (this is why `$.browser` is bad)

Comment: Where is `data` defined in your onload callback?

Comment: Why do you even bother testing for IE and doing ajax manually when you are using jQuery anyways? $.ajax works just fine in IE6/7/8/9/10/11

Comment: Also if you are doing cross domain requests, that probably means you have access to the other domain, since you need to configure the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header anyways. And since XDomain requests are somewhat broken (at least in IE < 9) you should probably be using jsonP if you can. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx | http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors | http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

Comment: @KevinB Not to mention $.browser has been deprecated from jQuery since 5 versions back anyways